# Find the Top 10 results from a table using Castle ActiveRecord

Tags: c#, nhibernate, activerecord, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to get say the top 10 scores for the users of my application. I'm usually using something along the lines of

```
User.SlicedFindAll(0, 10, 
NHibernate.Expression.Expression.Eq("IsActive", true), 
NHibernate.Expression.Order.Desc("Score")
```

which is usually used for pagination purposes. However, I don't want to add any constraint (WHERE clause) to my request. Hence I tried something along the lines of

```
User.SlicedFindAll(0, 10, 
null, 
NHibernate.Expression.Order.Desc("Score")
```

but this throws a NullReferenceException. Any pointers? (I guess SlicedFindAll is not a good choice)

Google didn't help on that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this overload:

```
public static T[] SlicedFindAll(int firstResult, int maxResults, NHibernate.Expression.Order[] orders, params NHibernate.Expression.ICriterion[] criteria)
```

in your case it would be:

```
User.SlicedFindAll(0, 10, new[] {Order.Desc("Score")})
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended doing even if I feel this is probably not optimal :)

Comment: SlicedFindAll reference docs: http://api.castleproject.org/html/Overload_Castle_ActiveRecord_ActiveRecordMediator_1_SlicedFindAll.htm

Answer (score 0):

I prefer LINQ:

```
ActiveRecordLinq.AsQueryable<User>().Take(10)
```

It should perfectly evaluate to sth like

```
select top 10 * from User
```